# Display random image from database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

i want to display image with randomly selected or the one that i choose from database.

```css
thumbnail {
float: left;
}
```

```html
$query1=mysqli_query($db_con,"select * from image_tb");
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
   $img = "<th><img src='".$row['image']."' width='260px';height='180px;' ></th>";
   $image_number = $row['id'];
   
   

<div class="block-content collapse in">
     <div class="row-fluid padd-bottom">
     <div class="span3">
//i want to display here the first image on my database but i don't know how to code it properly. 
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      if (1 == $image_number){
          <?php echo "$img"; ?>
      }
       </a>
       </div>
       <div class="span3">
//the 2nd image from database
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      if (2 == $image_number){
          <?php echo "$img"; ?>
      }
      </div>   
     </div>
<?php
  }
?>
     </div>
```

I don't really know how to code it properly.

Comment: First of all, comments don't work like this: `//` in HTML. They work like this: `<!-- Comment Here -->`. Second of all, you need to put your non-HTML code inside of a specific HTML element called `<script>`. I suggest you take a little tutorial on how HTML and scripts work. You've written all your other code as text in the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$query1=mysqli_query($db_con,"select id, image from image_tb");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
   $images[$row['id']] = $row; //the $images array will store the images id from image_tb as an index, so you can call it directly like $images[x]
}
   $random_img = array_rand($image); // this will give you a random image
?>

<div class="block-content collapse in">
     <div class="row-fluid padd-bottom">
     <div class="span3">
    <!-- i want to display here the first image on my database but i don't know how to code it properly.-->
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<?php $images[$random_image] ?>" width="260px" height="180px">
       </a>
       </div>
       <div class="span3">
    <!-- the 2nd image from database -->
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<?php $images[$random_image] ?>" width="260px" height="180px">
      </a>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write another function to get random image,
Your query should look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM image_tb ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

This in my opinion seems to be most efficient way of selecting random row from database. Then you can do whatever you want with in in PHP.

But the con is you have to run two queries. You might try to use union like:

```
SELECT * FROM image_tb ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 UNION SELECT * FROM image_tb ORDER BY id LIMIT 2;
```

which will give you 3 rows (first random) following two first pictures

**Haven't tested this**